# Wordpress: "get_the_ID" is changed after "get_posts"

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This might be an understanding problem on my end, but here is the run down:

I'm using the ACF plugin, which can return a field-value with a get function. By default, this get-function will use the current ID (e.g. the current page or post) to look for the field. Problem: Somewhere in my page, I'm using a loop "$posts = get_posts($defargs);" to check for other content. But after this loop, the current page id (checked with "get_the_ID") has changed, probably to the last item within the posts-loop.

I need to prevent this from happening or to reset the current ID after the loop somehow so that the function "get_the_ID" will return the same ID ... which should be that of the current page ... before and after the post-loop.

I could find a workaround, e.g. storing the ID in a var and use this in my ACF-functions, but I just want to understand why this is happening, and how I could prevent this or restore/reload the current page ID. (Btw. get_post($storedID); does not work)

Comment: You sure it's using `get_posts()`? That function should not alter the global post data.  Try calling it something other than `$posts`

Comment: Or try `wp_reset_postdata()`

Comment: Hi there ... first up, you are right ... with both. wp_reset did solve my problem, and yes, get_posts wasnt the culprit, it seems to be this code: $pro_num = $post->ID; ... which I used within the loop. So thank you! :-)